# Восстановление пароля PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.7

всем привет, есть задача на восстановление пароля в Laravel
я решила воспользоваться методами из-под коробки

мой код:

```
class ResettingPasswordController extends APIController
{

    private PasswordBroker $passwordBroker;


    public function __construct(PasswordBroker $passwordBroker)
    {
        $this->passwordBroker = $passwordBroker;
    }

    public function forgot(ForgotPasswordRequest $request)
    {
        
        User::where($email)->firstOrFail();

        $this->passwordBroker->sendResetLink($request->only('email'));
    }

    public function reset(ResetPasswordRequest $request)
    {
            $reset_password_status = Password::reset(
            $request->only('email', 'token', 'password'),
            function ($user, $password) {
                $user->password = $password;
                $user->save();
            }
        );

        if ($reset_password_status == Password::INVALID_TOKEN) {
            throw new TokenCollectionException("Invalid token provided");
        }


    }
}
```

в рутах я прописала следующее

Route::post('password/email', [ResettingPasswordController::class, 'forgot']);
Route::post('/reset', [ResettingPasswordController::class, 'reset']);

делала все по тюториалу https://dev.to/chandreshhere/laravel-7-forgot-password-apis-using-inbuilt-laravel-methods-4ij0

не могу найти ошибку, заранее спасибо

на почту ничего не приходит

Comment: Явная проблема здесь что пароль не захеширован. А по самому вопросу, у вас почта настроена в ларе?

Comment: @Walfter , нет код оказался рабочим - проблема была в настройке маилтрепа